# Getting invalid json error while getting json value from jsp

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, jsp

Main Jsp

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

</table>
    </form>
```

Jquery :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "json.jsp",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "extn" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

json.jsp

```
    response.setContentType("application/json"); 
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
response.setHeader("pragma", "no-cache");
response.getWriter().write("{data: [ { name: \"Tiger Nixon\", position: \"System Architect\",office: \"Edinburgh\",extn: \"5421\",start_date: \"2011/04/25\",salary: \"$320,800\"}]}");
response.getWriter().flush();
response.getWriter().close();
```

objects.txt

```
{ "data": [ { "name": "Tiger Nixon", "position": "System Architect", "salary": "$320,800", "start_date": "2011/04/25", "office": "Edinburgh", "extn": "5421" } ] }
```

Response when passing json.jsp :

[image]

Response when passing objects.txt :

[image]

Getting invalid json response.
But the same code works if i call objects.txt file

Comment: You are missing quotes around property names in your json.jsp, i.e. `{ data: [{ name: \"Tiger Nixon\", ...` should be `{ \"data\": [{ \"name\": \"Tiger Nixon\:, ...`.

Comment: Welcome, please ask something next time.You can't expect us to start looking for a problem without any information. You did provide a lot of information about your data (that's good) but explain the context and your problem too.

Comment: thnx @ Jozef Chocholacek . It worked :) appreciated